# Prove that $c:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with $t\rightarrow (t^2,t^3)$ is not regular.

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

Prove that $c:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with $t\rightarrow (t^2,t^3)$ is not regular.

Ok so this is probably a well-known problem of Differential Geometry but I have problem understanding it.Any online source explaining it in details will be helpful.

Otherwise I am trying to show the proof of the class notes. I am giving the images below as I think that if I write it here people might think that I have made some typing mistakes or stuff.[image][image]

Comment: A $C^1$ curve $c$ is regular if and onlly if $c'(t)$ is never $0$ (the zero vector). In this case, $c'(t)=(2t,3t^2)$, which is $=(0,0)$ for $t=0$. Therefore, the curve is not regular. QED

Comment: The fact that it's not regular is obvious from the definition. The interesting part is that there is no reparametrization that makes it regular. But the fact that you _post_ a proof of this fact and then ask for a proof is curious...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No the proof is hard to understand. And I meant to ask that there does not exist any regular parametrization...the interesting part.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes we have a misunderstanding...I meant to ask that there cannot be any regular parametrization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range of $c$ is $\{(x,x^{3/2}): x\ge 0\}.$ Let's call the range $c^*.$ Suppose $\gamma (t) =(f(t),g(t))$ is a $C^1$ map of $\mathbb R$ onto $c^*.$ Then $f$ maps $\mathbb R$ surjectively onto $[0,\infty).$ Hence $f(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0.$ This implies $f$ has a minimum at $t_0,$ which tells us $f'(t_0) = 0.$ Now $g(t)=f(t)^{3/2}$ for all $t.$ Thus $g'(t_0) = (3/2)f(t_0)^{1/2}f'(t_0) = 0.$ Therefore $\gamma'(t_0) = (0,0),$ proving $\gamma $ is not regular.

Comment: Thanks a lot...this was what I was asking. If you don't mind can you suggest me a book that explains things as nicely as you have in your answer?

Comment: I don't really know much about differential geometry, much to my regret. In the general vicinity is the book Differential Topology by Guillemin and Pollack, as nice an introduction to a topic as I've seen.